# AWS Encryption Java SDK : org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyPairGeneratorSpi$EC.initialize(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, cryptography, aws-sdk, bouncycastle, apache-nifi

I am trying to use AWS Encryption SDK in Custom NiFi processor, but keep on facing this error trace:

> failed to process due to com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.exception.AwsCryptoException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec; rolling back session: {}
>   com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.exception.AwsCryptoException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec
>       at com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.DefaultCryptoMaterialsManager.getMaterialsForEncrypt(DefaultCryptoMaterialsManager.java:63)
>       at com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.AwsCrypto.encryptData(AwsCrypto.java:243)
>       at com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.AwsCrypto.encryptString(AwsCrypto.java:300)
>       at com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.AwsCrypto.encryptString(AwsCrypto.java:288)
>       at org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.awsencryption.AwsEncryptContent$1.process(AwsEncryptContent.java:196)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2785)
>       at org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.awsencryption.AwsEncryptContent.onTrigger(AwsEncryptContent.java:186)
>       at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1120)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec
>       at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyPairGeneratorSpi$EC.initialize(Unknown Source)
>       at com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.internal.TrailingSignatureAlgorithm$ECDSASignatureAlgorithm.generateKey(TrailingSignatureAlgorithm.java:88)
>       at com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.DefaultCryptoMaterialsManager.generateTrailingSigKeyPair(DefaultCryptoMaterialsManager.java:151)
>       at com.amazonaws.encryptionsdk.DefaultCryptoMaterialsManager.getMaterialsForEncrypt(DefaultCryptoMaterialsManager.java:54)
>       ... 18 common frames omitted

I have already included bouncyCastle dependencies in the project for `bcprov-ext-jdk15on` and also `bcprov-jdk15on` for latest version.

On execution of `encryptString` method, it throws the mentioned exception.

Any idea what could be wrong here?